# "Error while loading shared libraries" even though the library in question is present in /usr/lib

Tags: libraries, manjaro, shared-library

I am trying to run [Scala](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/) on my Linux Manjaro laptop, but whenever I try to run the program, it displays the following error:

```
./scala: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkada.so.2.24.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, I have verified that the shared object file in question is present in `/usr/lib`. I have tried running `ldconfig` as root, but that did not resolve the problem. When I run `ldd scala`, the relevant output I receive is:

```
...
libgtkada.so.2.24.4 => not found
...
```

This makes no sense to me, since `libgtkada.so.2.24.4` is present in my `/usr/lib` folder. What should I do to resolve this problem?

EDIT: The output of `strace ./scala` is as follows:

```
execve("./scala", ["./scala"], 0x7ffd5332dbc0 /* 23 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=7780 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x98b7000
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7726000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=319201, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 319201, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xf76d8000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib32/tls/i686/sse2/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/tls/i686/sse2", 0xffbe4c20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/tls/i686/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/tls/i686", 0xffbe4c20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/tls/sse2/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/tls/sse2", 0xffbe4c20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/tls/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/tls", 0xffbe4c20)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/i686/sse2/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/i686/sse2", 0xffbe4c20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/i686/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/i686", 0xffbe4c20)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/sse2/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32/sse2", 0xffbe4c20)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib32/libgtkada.so.2.24.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib32", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=49152, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="./scala", iov_len=7}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libra"..., iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="libgtkada.so.2.24.4", iov_len=19}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="cannot open shared object file", iov_len=30}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="No such file or directory", iov_len=25}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10./scala: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkada.so.2.24.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 126
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
alex@laptop ~/S/scala-
```

Running `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` produces no output. Is that normal?

Comment: paste your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Or show (via `strace` or the like) what files `./scala` is attempting to read.

Comment: Note the strace is showing it is trying to load from /usr/lib32 rather than lib. Is this a 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: `/usr/lib32` looks like a 32-bit version of the library is being looked for. Perhaps install that, or rebuild as 64-bit?

Comment: Looks like a 32/64-bit mismatch to me. The library is present in /use/lib, but scala is trying to locate it in /use/lib32.

Comment: @icarus I'm using a 64-bit system.

Comment: `Process PID=7780 runs in 32 bit mode.` Which version of Scala did you download?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I feel so idiotic now- I never realized there was a 64-bit version of Scala available for download, just below the 32-bit version. Thank you so much!

Comment: Someone should probably answer this question. Or it could probably be closed as a dupe. I'm sure this question has come up before.